# My Windows 7 shortcut with arguments keep getting changed

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, shortcuts, command-line-arguments

I have a shortcut to chrome on my desktop with a parameter:

```
Target: C:\Users\Eyal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
```

Every few days (I can't figure out the trigger), it gets re-written to this:

```
Target: C:\Users\Eyal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

The parameter disappears.  My only guess is that maybe Windows doesn't like that the `Target` isn't a file and rewrites it.  It happens about once every 2-3 days.

Is there a way to make a shortcut with a parameter that I won't have to keep fixing?

Comment: Are you sure it is not just chrome updating itself? Try to create a second (identical) shortcut manually and use that one

Comment: This was a shortcut that I made myself.  I right-click-dragged chrome to my desktop, made a shortcut, and modified the target.

Answer (score 1):

Probably either chrome or some other software is messing with the shortcut.

**Options:**

- Try naming the shortcut differently than the Default name.
- Create shortcut manually i.e. by right clicking on the desktop and select New>Shortcut and follow on screen instructions.
- Alternatively you can use Batch file to launch chrome in the mode you want. (This will not be affected by updates or anything like that)
  Create a text file, paste following command to it, save it with
  extension **.bat**.

  ```
  START C:\Users\Eyal\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --allow-file-access-from-files
  EXIT
  ```

Double Click the file to launch chrome. (You can customize the icon to make it look like the chrome shortcut)